# Why should I consider size of revolving line always to be positive in unit circle, trigonometry?

Tags: trigonometry

I'm reading a book, Plane Trigonometry by SL Loney.

Consider the diagram in article 50. In according to Article 50 OB' and OA' is negative direction and OB and OA are positive. In Aricle 52(First Quadrant:) OP<sub>1</sub> is considered positive. In (Second Quadrant:) M<sub>2</sub>O is considered negative while P<sub>2</sub> is considered positive. This is why sine of angle is considered to be positive in 2<sup>nd</sup> quadrant.

My question is if OP<sub>2</sub> is running towards negative side why don we considered its length to be negative?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This is a really antique treatment.  (The book is over $100$ years old.)  There is a much simpler explanation.  Have you learned about coordinate geometry?

Comment: The length of $OP$ is always constant, namely, the radius of the circle which is never negative. In 2nd quadrant, $MP_2$ is positive, and hence sine is positive.